# Could a geomagnetic storm disrupt the functioning of nerves?

Tags: neuroscience, central-nervous-system, peripheral-nervous-system, autonomic-nervous-system

It is known that geomagnetic storms can cause power grid outages. Can they also disrupt the functioning of nerves/the nervous system?

Comment: We expect questions posted here to show some evidence of prior research effort.